# Zxing Xamarin Forms BlackScreen on Resume

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, zxing, zxing.net

Today I found out a Issue on Xamarin Forms (Android) - iOS works well.

Zxing is Initialized in the Constructor.
Permissions are correctly set.

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Navigate to the Scanner Page. (don't scan anything)
2. Click on the "Home" Button which brings you to the start Screen.
3. Navigate Back in the App with the Android "App-Switcher"

-> Now you get a Black Screen.

if I go back into the app the Method
`protected override void OnAppearing()`
 is called.
here I set `zxing.IsScanning = true;`

If I navigate inside my App like Navigate away from scanner Page and navigate back - everything works pretty fine.

Zxing Version: 2.3.2 and also tested with 2.3.1
XamarinForms Version: 2.5.0.91635

Works on iOS 10-11 on iPhone SE, 7, X
Does not Work on Android 6,7 on Galaxy S7, Huawei P8, LG G3

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `Xamarin.Forms` and calling the `InitializeComponent();` in `OnAppearing()` solves the problem (maybe not the most elegant solution, but it works fine)